# Laravel - Internal Server Error and Forbidden Access

Tags: laravel, apache, laravel-5, file-permissions, chmod

I use cPanel tranfer tool to copy the website from a server to another server, but after that, I got `Internal Server Error`...

To solve that problem I run the command:

```
sudo chown -R perica:perica /home/perica/public_html/
```

after that:

```
sudo find /home/perica -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \; 

sudo find /home/perica -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

but I got again the same error.

I also try to     `sudo find /home/perica -type f -exec chmod 700 {} \;` but then I got error

```
 Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /admin on this server.
Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Also, my storage folder and bootstrap permission is 777.

What is the problem?

**UPDATE: I delete .htaccess file and now I see the Laravel folder structure but when I navigate a browser to domain.com/public folder again I got error.**

Comment: Is your webserver running as user `perica`? Is anything written to the logfiles? Also Laravel 5.1 is old, the current version is 5.7. If you have to put /public at the end of your url then your webserver is configured wrong.

Comment: no, I just navigate browser to that URL when I delete .htaccess

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)